# how to share data between taghelpers?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I have a class that contains two tagHelpers.

```
[htmlTargetElement("div")]
public class DivTagHelper :TagHelpers {
public override void process(TagHelperContext context, TahHelperOutput output)
 //codes
}

[htmlTargetElement("button", ParentTag="div")]
public class ButtonTagHelper :TagHelpers {
public override void process(TagHelperContext context, TahHelperOutput output)
 //codes
}
```

One acts on the DIV and the other acts on the Buttons.
I need to generate values in one of the tagHelpers(Div) and share them for other tagHelpers(Button).

There is a solution to this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you must use **TagHelperContext.items** property.

This property is a collection of dictionary that can act as a place to share data between taghelpers.

```
[htmlTargetElement("div")]
public class DivTagHelper :TagHelpers {
public override void process(TagHelperContext context, TahHelperOutput output)
 context.Items["myData"]="somethings";
}


[htmlTargetElement("button", ParentTag="div")]
public class ButtonTagHelper :TagHelpers {
public override void process(TagHelperContext context, TahHelperOutput output)
 string strName=context.Items["myData"];
}
```